# Is there a way to SUMIFS based on a condition for a output range?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

The practical example is: I need to sum the total amount of time worked on a week for specific roles (engineer, etc..) within the company. What I need is to sum a column of values only if the name on the left has a specific role. I could put that role on a column next to the name, but as I would like to keep a history of employee promotion, the role is on a similar week basis table.

Following, we can see the workload tab (with the name and column to sum for example, sum column E) and the people with the name and the roles A21:AB37.

So I am trying to, for example, place the sum of hours(workload) from 'estag 1' people (name matches 'people' tab) on the 'data' tab, on C40

Following is a copy of the Sheets, feel free to update:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GgQGM7Pca0P3kdZurIBwQP9EMTILswc3sIWF11xXMMM/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried a sumif with filter inside, query, vlookup, but I couldn't get to a working function.

Any suggestions??

Comment: what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(people!$A$24:$A, people!C$24:C=$B40)))
```

and drag down and to the right as needed

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(
 FILTER(people!$A$24:$A, people!C$24:C=$B40), "♥"), 
 {people!$A$2:$A, people!C$2:C}, 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The returned value is wrong. For estag 1, for example, it should be 0 (name 3 and name 6 hours).

For 'sócio'. it should be 40 - name 4 and name 14.
Did you get the idea?

Comment: It Worked perfectly!! 
Thank you very much