# I would like to SUMIF workload based on roles and allocated Projects

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

I've posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59184293/is-there-a-way-to-sumifs-based-on-a-condition-for-a-output-range/59184564?noredirect=1#comment104590585_59184564) a few days ago, and @player0 Helped me with it.

I would like to go a step further and sum the workload for people based not on roles only, but projects too.
So, for example, on [the Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GgQGM7Pca0P3kdZurIBwQP9EMTILswc3sIWF11xXMMM/edit?usp=sharing), I would like to, on 'data' tab, cell C55, insert the SUM of hours from 'workload' tab, column E, on which name on A column matches names from 'people' tab that are on '**Estag. 1**' role -> A24:C37 range **and also** matches the project from 'workload' tab, column B, with 'data' tab, column B.

The expected output for the firts column on 'data' tab C55:C64 is 'hardcoded' on C67.
Explanation: there are only 20hours 'Estag 1' people working on 'Appao' project.
And 2 'Estag. 1' people working on 'Eu vo' project. Summing 30 in total for this last project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(workload!$E$2:$E, REGEXMATCH(workload!$A$2:$A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 FILTER(people!$A$23:$A, people!C$23:C=$B$40))), workload!$B$2:$B=$B55))
```

[image: 9]